# Java while loop doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean run = true;
    while (run) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to MetricMan - the best converter in town!");
        System.out.println("Choose and option:");
        System.out.println("A) Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        System.out.println("B) Celcius to Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("C) Miles to Kilometers");
        System.out.println("D) Kilometers to Miles");
        System.out.println("E) Inches to Centimeters");
        System.out.println("F) Centimeters to Inches");
        System.out.println("X) Quit the program");

        System.out.print("Your choice > ");
        String choice = kb.nextLine();

        double output; int input;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of ");
        switch (choice) { // do actions according to the user's choice. convert and display
        case "A":
            System.out.print("Farenheit > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertFtoC(input);
            System.out.println(input+" farenheit is "+output+" celsius");
            break;
        case "B":
            System.out.print("Celsius > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertCtoF(input);
            System.out.println(input+" celsius is "+output+" farenheit");
            break;
        case "C":
            System.out.print("miles > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertMtoK(input);
            System.out.println(input+" miles is "+output+" kilometres");
            break;
        case "D":
            System.out.print("kilometres > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertKtoM(input);
            System.out.println(input+" kilometres is "+output+" miles");
            break;
        case "E":
            System.out.print("inches > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertItoC(input);
            System.out.println(input+" inches is "+output+" centimeters");
            break;
        case "F":
            System.out.print("centimeters > ");
            input = kb.nextInt();
            output = convertCtoI(input);
            System.out.println(input+" centimeters is "+output+" inches");
            break;
        case "X":
            System.out.println(); System.out.println();
            System.out.println("May the odds be ever metric!");
            run = false;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println();
        kb.nextLine();
    }
} // end of main()
```

there's my main method. As seen in the code, when X has been entered the code should stop running straight away, however its actual output is

```
...
Your choice > X
Enter the number of 

May the odds be ever metric!
```

there is a "enter the number of " before the actualy intended output and I see no reason for it to be there. Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: You're outputting it after you read input, but before you switch to decide what to do with it: 
System.out.print("Enter the number of ");

Comment: General question: Why are you creating a new Scanner object on each iteration? That's pretty awful.

Comment: If the code is supposed to stop after you input an X, you should have put a `run=false;break;` after the input line. Otherwise, you still have a lot of code that executes before you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `System.out.print("Enter the number of ");` in every case .So thats why its printing when you entered `X` so try to put `System.out.print("Enter the number of ");` inside `if(check if string entered is not X)` like below

```
if(!choice.equals("X")){
System.out.print("Enter the number of ");
}
```

**OR**

put `System.out.print("Enter the number of ");` inside each switch case where you want it as pointed by @Tanmoy

Answer (score 1):

That line occurs every time you go through the loop. One way to fix this is to make that call in each case statement except for X.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of ");

    switch (choice) { // do actions according to the user's choice. convert and display
```

so you are basically printing this before switch, so the output is expected, you may want to call inside cases rather outside switch, when its x, just quit.